# Simple tool/steps for obfuscating/scrubbing production data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am involved in a project where I need to provide subset of our production data (for a date range) to one of my co-workers for trouble shooting.I would like to insert a scrubbed subset of the production data into a new database table that my co-worker can access. Please suggest best approach to achieve this.

Comment: question makes no sense as is.

Comment: Please check whether it makes sense now

Comment: yet another suspicious 2 upvotes for a question which is not currently a valid question. And one favorite!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to update the data after copying it to a new table to something that meets enough criteria forit to still be used.

We have a function that does a replacement of letters by letters, spaces by spaces for textual data, and randomised number for numbers.

Comment: A good tip I saw on a similar question was to anonymise based on the row ID so a customer "Joe", "Bloggs" would be changed to "FirstName123", "LastName123".  Helps enormously with finding which column data is coming from and which record!